# Error while building new react native iOS app due to glog library build error

Tags: react-native

Getting compilation errors with glog static library installed via pod. Using Xcode 12.3 and glog version is 0.3.5. Attaching a screenshot for the errors from Xcode build logs. [Xcode build error logs with new react native app]

[image]

Please provide solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

you should try cleaning your build project in xcode then try to delete your podfile.lock then pod install, hope this helps.